# Il contrario di 'unicum'

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request, latin

'Unicum' è una parola che ricorre piuttosto frequentemente ed è assai evocativa, forse si dice che è icastica.

È una parola latina, sì, ma fa parte dell'italiano corrente e forse anche del vocabolario italiano.

La domanda è: Esiste una parola latina, comunque facente parte del vocabolario corrente, che sia altrettanto icastica come 'unicum', ma che significhi il contrario?

Comment: A me non viene niente in mente. Tendo a pensare che non esista. Se esiste è sicuramente molto meno usato di *unicum*. La qual cosa ha, secondo me, anche un certo senso: mi sembra molto più frequente fare riferimento al concetto di *unicum* piuttosto che al suo opposto (si loda una cosa perché è un *unicum*, appunto, ma non perché è una cosa come altre cinquanta; ci si vanta di essere un *unicum*, non di essere come tutti gli altri).

Comment: Prova a cercare [qui](http://www.homolaicus.com/linguaggi/glossario_latino.htm).

Comment: [Ulteriore significato di *unicum*](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicum).

Answer (score 5):

Bisogna distinguere.

"Unicum" in quanto parola latina ha diversi "contrari" in latino, ad esempio "pluralis" [numeroso].

In quanto termine usato in italiano in modo pregnante (con un corredo di  sfumature al di là del significato latino), non ha un contrario di simile peso (ed il contrario latino non è usato in un contesto italiano).

La parola stessa rappresenta un unicum...